# Can Uncanny Trickster Stack With Magical Trickster?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, prestige-class

In The Complete Scoundrel, there are two prestige classes: Magical Trickster and Uncanny Trickster. Both have three defined levels.

Magical Trickster, in addition to its own inherent goodness, provides spells and casting as +1 level of your current casting class for levels 2 and 3.

Uncanny Trickster, in addition to its own inherent goodness, provides "+1 level of existing class features," again at levels 2 and 3.

Would it therefore be valid for a character who, assuming he meets all the prerequisites of both, to take a level of Magical Trickster, then three levels of Uncanny Trickster, and functionally end up with all three levels of *both* stacked on top of his pre-existing spell casting class?

Comment: Related: http://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/32259/what-are-the-rules-for-multiple-prestige-classes and http://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/55925/what-does-it-mean-when-a-prestige-class-says-1-level-of-existing-class

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Yes, this is legit, but there's more to it than that

The uncanny trickster (*Complete Scoundrel* 67-70) special ability class features says

> At each level after 1st, you gain class features (including spellcasting ability) and an increase in effective level as if you had also gained a level in a class to which you belonged before adding the prestige class level. You do not, however, gain the benefit of your previous class’s Hit Dice, attack progression, skill points, or saving throws. If you had more than one class before becoming an uncanny trickster, you must decide to which class to add each level for the purpose of determining class features. (67)

Thus, *after* the first level, uncanny trickster advancement can advance a base or prestige classes' special abilities in addition to its own. The prestige class uncanny trickster is in no way limited to advancing *only* the prestige class magical trickster (45-8), and the two prestige classes have no special relationship.

[The other prestige class that has a similar feature](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/48728/8610) is legacy champion (*Weapons of Legacy* 19-22)

Comment: I hadn't figured that they'd had a special relationship, just that they were very synergistic for a skilled, skill-trick-wielding character. :)

Comment: @JohnRudy The question's focus on those two classes and the similarity in the classes' names seemed to make clarifying necessary. No harm either way. Be aware that losing those 2 caster levels *really* hurts; no number of skill tricks can *ever* replace casting higher-level spells.

Comment: The spell point is a big loss, no doubt. TBH, the character in question was slated to die due to being off-balance, but our group's decision to remove PC access to the polymorph school saved him. (It was actually my idea. Combat got boring with polymorph and this character.)